# iOS webapp performance safari vs home screen start

Tags: ios, performance, web-applications, javascript-engine

I read [an article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/15/apple_ios_throttles_web_apps_on_home_screen/) recently which states that web apps on iOS launched from the home screen running in full screen mode have slower performance than webapps running inside safari.

Then I found a [followup article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/06/17/apple_ios5_adds_nitro_to_home_screen_web_apps/) to it which seems to sugguest that the issue above is fixed.

Does anyone know if this is confirmed?

Comment: In articles you mentioned they talking about difference between webapps speed started inside MobileSafari and webapps started from home screen (full screen mode). Not native apps (which were developed using Xcode and posted to AppStore).

Answer (score 2):

According to information from [appleinsider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/06/17/ios_5_supports_speedy_nitro_javascript_for_full_screen_web_apps.html), ios5 beta fixes that problem and now Nitro JavaScript engine enabled on Web.app.

I've iOS 5 installed on my iphone4 and updated [SunSpider JavaScript testing framework 0.9.1](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html) (to be able to start as fullscreen web application under ios). And I've started subspider several times in fullscreen webapp mode and in Safari mobile. So, see my results below (images are clickable):

[image: Safari webapp]


[image: Fullscreen weapp]

May be something was fixed (apple insider provides 4 vs 10 seconds difference), but I **can't** say that performance is equals in both cases (3756.5ms vs 5243.8ms for those who can't see images).

**UPD**

Small interesting note about UIWebView, it is impossible to use Nitro-enabled JavaScript engine in native applications (I mean applications designed in Xcode and posted to AppStore) because Nitro JIT requires to be able to use dynamic code signing.

**UPD**

Look at [iOS 5 Top 10 Browser Performance Changes on blaze.io](http://www.blaze.io/mobile/ios5-top10-performance-changes/), Seems Apple enabled Nitro for Fullscreen WebApps in iOS5 (nice statistics in article).